# Unity Says There is No Namespace called "Player"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am trying make an infinite level generator that gets level parts I give to it and mix's them up to make infinite long an unique levels for me. but the problem is that When I Typed [SerializeField] private Player player; it said No namespace called "Player" which is odd because There are other code's were Player player is used and it works.Maybe I am just dumb but anyway here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    private const float PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART = 200f;

    [SerializeField] private Transform levelPart_Start;
    [SerializeField] private List<Transform> levelPartList;
    [SerializeField] private Player player;

    private Vector3 lastEndPosition;

    private void Awake() {
        lastEndPosition = levelPart_Start.Find("EndPosition").position;

        int startingSpawnLevelParts = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < startingSpawnLevelParts; i++) {
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
    }

    private void Update() {
        if (Vector3.Distance(player.GetPosition(), lastEndPosition) < PLAYER_DISTANCE_SPAWN_LEVEL_PART) {
            SpawnLevelPart();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnLevelPart() {
        Transform chosenLevelPart = levelPartList[Random.Range(0, levelPartList.Count)];
        Transform lastLevelPartTransform = SpawnLevelPart(chosenLevelPart, lastEndPosition);
        lastEndPosition = lastLevelPartTransform.Find("EndPosition").position;
    }

    private Transform SpawnLevelPart(Transform levelPart, Vector3 spawnPosition) {
        Transform levelPartTransform = Instantiate(levelPart, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        return levelPartTransform;
    }

}
```

I have tried to make in into a game object but then I got even more errors

Comment: how should *we* know what a `Player` is in your code? Where is it defined?

Comment: Are you missing a "using" perhaps? I assume your "Player" is defined in another file.

Comment: Find the namespace where the Player class is defined and add a using namespace; line to the top of your code. I've also run into similar naming issues like this when I have had a class with the same name as a namespace.

Answer (score -1):

No namespace called "Player"
It makes me think that the problem is in the Using.
In some parts of your code it accepts it because you are using it or it is in the same namespace.
Assuming it is called like this, try adding the using as follows

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Player; (it can change but should be like this)
```